# Booting Problem - Ubuntu GNOME 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, drivers, amd-graphics

After installing AMD Driver for the HD 8670M graphics card I restarted the os and now it freezes on "Started User Manager for UID 121."

It seems that, this problem have happened in other versions of the OS especially with Nvidia graphics card, but my machine has an AMD.
Does someone could help me please? How should proceed? 
I don't have lots of experience with those kind of problems.
By the way, Alt+F2 it's not working...

Comment: I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To access the virtual console press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. If you are able to login, try to see if there are package dependencies issues.

You can do this by:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```